# Add renderer in @view_config from configuration?

Tags: python-3.x, pyramid

How do I supply a configured value to a `@view_config`-decorated function or class?

E.g.

```
@view_config(route_name='example', renderer=some_config['template.name'])
class MyClass(BaseView):
    ...
```

Or

```
@view_defaults(route_name='example', renderer=some_config['template.name2'])
class MyClass2(BaseView):
    ...
```

Or

```
@view_config(route_name='example', renderer=some_config['template.name3'])
def method3(request):
    ...
```

It's very hard to know where to start, as I'm trying to edit a pyramid plugin, which pulls together its config in an `includeme` function, so it doesn't have anything obvious that I can include, and it's hard to know what's available to the `@view_config` decorator.

Answer (score 2):

You can add views using [declarative](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/glossary.html#term-declarative-configuration) configuration (what you are doing now using `@view_config` or alternatively using [imperative configuration](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/glossary.html#term-imperative-configuration) by calling `config.add_view()` method.

In this case, as you need to access the Pyramid registry and settings file, it is easier to do adding the views imperatively.

In your `__init__.py` you can do:

```
  settings = config.registry.settings
  # You need to call config.add_route("foobar") to map view to URL also

  config.add_view('views.MyClass', route_name="foobar", renderer=settings['template.name3'])
```

Then in your `views.py`:

```
  class MyClass(BaseView):
       pass
```

`@view_config()` and [add_view()](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/config.html#pyramid.config.Configurator.add_view) arguments are equal.

I thin kyou can also mix `view_config` and `add_view()` arguments for the same view, but I am not sure aobut this. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for this; I was hoping to use declarative because the plugin I'm editing uses inherited `@view_default`s, so it'll turn into a lot of imperative config. Or can I do defaults imperatively?

Comment: @RobertGrant: In theory you can extract any @view_defaults() information from the imported objects run-time. Just poke deep enough internal attributes of modules and classes. But it could be more clean to use `add_view()` for everything.

Comment: You can get settings from threadlocal ``from pyramid.threadlocal import get_current_registry`` like ``settings = get_current_registry().settings`` and then use it in decorator ``@view_defaults(renderer=settings['template.name2'])``